# How to set a QWebEngineProfile to a QWebEngineView

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to set different QWebEngineProfiles to different QWebEngineViews meaning each view will have its own cookie store. I cant find any documentation on it therefore all help would be greatly appreciated.
Any suggestion of another method of setting independent cookie stores to independent webviews will also help. Cheers.

Code is below (connecting the signal did not format properly here but rest assured it is correct in the real code):

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.browser={}
        self.cookiestore={}
        self.page={}
        No = input("No: ")
        for i in range(int(No)):
            self.browser[str(i)] = QWebEngineView()
            storagename = str(i)
            self.cookiestore[str(i)] = QWebEngineProfile(storagename, self.browser[str(i)])
            self.page[str(i)] = QWebEnginePage(self.cookiestore[str(i)], self.browser[str(i)])
            self.browser[str(i)].setPage(self.page[str(i)])
            self.browser[str(i)].load(QUrl("https://www.google.com"))
      self.browser[str(i)].loadFinished.connect(lambda:self._loaded(str(i)))

    def _loaded(self, No):
        self.browser[No].page().toHtml(self._callable)
    def _callable(self, data):
        self.html = data
        if "" in self.html:
            print("Done")
        else:
            print("wait")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to establish a `QWebEngineProfile` to a `QWebEngineView` you must do it through a `QWebEnginePage` as I show below:

```
webview = QWebEngineView()
profile = QWebEngineProfile("somestorage", webview)
webpage = QWebEnginePage(profile, webview)
webview.setPage(webpage)
```

Example:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineProfile, QWebEnginePage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    views = []
    for i in range(5):
        webview = QWebEngineView()
        profile = QWebEngineProfile(f"storage-{i}", webview)
        webpage = QWebEnginePage(profile, webview)
        webview.setPage(webpage)
        webview.load(QUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48142341/how-to-set-a-qwebengineprofile-to-a-qwebengineview"))
        webview.show()
        views.append(webview)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I have done this however each QWebEngineView still share cookies between one another. How do I stop that from happening. Each QWebEngineView should have its own cookie store.

Comment: @Kermit Why do you say that you share the same cookies? In my case for each profile a new folder is generated where your respective cookies are stored. Have you established a storagename for each profile?

Comment: @Kermit I have just reviewed the cookies of each profile and they are different, they do not share them.

Comment: @Kermit In essence it is the same as what I did, although I do not like the input (), but I personally checked the cookies and they were different. How do you verify that they are the same?

Comment: @Kermit I need a feedback to help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162707/discussion-between-kermit-and-eyllanesc).