# How to specify user agent in QWebEngineView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, user-agent, qwebengineview

I am working on automating functionality on a web page using PyQt5. The page that is displayed in PyQt5 is substantially different from what is displayed in Chrome. If I was to change the User Agent, could I mimic Chromes functionality? And if so, how would I go about changing the User Agent in the following example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebEngineView()

profile = QWebEngineProfile()
profile.setHttpUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36")

# How do i set the profile in the web ???

web.load(QUrl("https://stackoverflow.com"))
web.show()
web.loadFinished.connect(on_load_finished)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48142341/how-to-set-a-qwebengineprofile-to-a-qwebengineview/48142651#48142651

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent):

> The **User-Agent** request header contains a characteristic string that
>   allows the network protocol peers to identify the application type,
>   operating system, software vendor or software version of the
>   requesting software user agent.

Some web pages will use the User Agent to display personalized content for your browser, for example, with the user-agent information you could deduce whether it supports AJAX or not.

**If I was to change the User Agent, could I mimic Chromes functionality?**

Probably yes, although although Google Chrome and Qt Webengine are based on chromium, each development group has created a new layer that can have different functionalities, for example, QtWebEngine has suppressed many chromium functionalities that are added in the new versions.

**How would I go about changing the User Agent?**

It is not necessary to create a new QWebEngineProfile since you can use the profile of the page:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    web = QWebEngineView()

    print(web.page().profile().httpUserAgent())

    web.page().profile().setHttpUserAgent(
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36"
    )
    web.load(QUrl("https://stackoverflow.com"))
    web.show()
    web.resize(640, 480)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you want to use the QWebEngineProfile then create a new QWebEnginePage:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage, QWebEngineProfile, QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    web = QWebEngineView()

    profile = QWebEngineProfile()
    profile.setHttpUserAgent(
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36"
    )

    page = QWebEnginePage(profile, web)
    web.setPage(page)
    web.load(QUrl("https://stackoverflow.com"))
    web.show()
    web.resize(640, 480)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```